# uninitialized constant occured when patch to Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I patch to my Redmine(Ver4.0.0) for [this](http://www.redmine.org/issues/306#note-29) patch file.

then, executed

```
bundle
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

and restarted redmine.

But following error occurred when I attached file to ticket.

```
[ActiveJob] [ExtractFulltextJob] [3daafa4a-4d90-43ce-a065-c4257176ca0f] Error performing ExtractFulltextJob (Job ID: 3daafa4a-4d90-43ce-a065-c4257176ca0f) from Async(text_extraction) in 9.77ms: NameError (uninitialized constant Redmine::TextExtractor):
/home/redmine/redmine/app/jobs/extract_fulltext_job.rb:7:in `perform'
```

I checked redmine/config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

and `redmine/lib/redmine/text_extractor.rb`

```
module Redmine
  class TextExtractor
  ....
```

But I could not understand why `uninitialized constant` error occured.

How to patch [this](http://www.redmine.org/issues/306#note-9) ?

Comment: You may have to require `%W(#{config.root}/lib/**/*.rb)` to get the nested files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rails5, production environment is not autoloaded by default.
So, I add `config.enable_dependency_loading = true` then works fine.